# Deploy Angular application in nginx, serve static resources ignoring url sub paths

Tags: angular, nginx, deployment

I am trying to configure nginx to deploy my angular application.

I am doing it with a virtual server and the ngnix server configuration is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        server_name app.mydomain.com;
        root /opt/prodat/gandalf/current;
        location / {
                try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }
        location ~ \.css {
                add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }
        location ~ \.js {
                add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }
}
```

When the initial page (index.html) loads everything works fine.

The problem is when I reload the page with an internal path to angular for example http://app.mydomain.com/activities/list

in the nginx log we see the following:

```
"GET /activities/vendor-es2015.js HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "http://app.mydomain.com/activities/list" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"
"GET /activities/main-es2015.js HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "http://app.mydomain.com/activities/list" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"
"GET /activities/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "http://app.mydomain.com/activities/list" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"
```

The requests include the activities and in all the responses a 404 Not Found is returned.

I have tried to fix it by adding these lines to the nginx configuration:

```
       location ~ /activities/(.*) {
                try_files /$1 $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;

        }
```

Apart from not working at all I do not like having to put each subpath of the angular application in the nginx configuration.

Can someone guide me on a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a hash location strategy https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy or configure nginx to redirect to index on a 404. The official documentation has a guide for that https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples

Comment: I would like to fix it in the nginx configuration so as not to have to modify the angular app.

Comment: Have you tried the second link from the Angular Documentation? I've only used for Apache rather than nginx but the idea should be similar; you can configure rewrite rules in your web server config that will redirect 404s back to your index.html so that nginx will serve it as a single-page application.

Comment: Hello Alex, I solved it by making the base path absolute in Angular's deploy. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it by modifying the base path of angular in the deploy.

The index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>eProdat - General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/isotipo.png" type="image/png">

  <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/colors/blue.css" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body class="fix-header fix-sidebar card-no-border">

  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/sticky-kit/sticky-kit.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/waves.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script></body>

</html>
```

In this way, the css and js paths are requested to be absolute without depending on the browser path.

Greetings.